# Magento total price not correct due to tax

Tags: php, magento

I've got custom issue with magento tax count. In shop I've got prices which includes tax rate and for example:

1. I want to order some product with price 4 (without tax: 3.28).
2. I want to order qty 37.
3. subtotal (without tax) is: 121.36 (correct),
4. **total is 148.00 which is not correct** (37 * 3.28 * 1.22 = 148.0592, so 148.06 to pay).

I've tried many different settings about tax, also tried to search which part of code is responsible for it, but cannot find it through the magento structure.

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I'm using Magento v. 1.9.2.4

edit: 
Finally I've found what is the problem, however still don't have an idea about good solution. I've changed for the test purpose 2 files:

1. \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php

   ```
    public function roundPrice($price)
           {
               return round($price, 4);
           }
   ```
2. \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal.php

   ```
   if ($quoteItem->getParentItem() && $quoteItem->isChildrenCalculated()) {
           $finalPrice = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getPriceModel()->getChildFinalPrice(
              $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct(),
              $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getQty(),
              $quoteItem->getProduct(),
              $quoteItem->getQty()
           );
           $item->setPrice($finalPrice)
               ->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
           $item->calcRowTotal();
       } else if (!$quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
           $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty()); $finalPrice = 4.0016;
           $item->setPrice($finalPrice)
               ->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
           $item->calcRowTotal();
           $this->_addAmount($item->getRowTotal());
           $this->_addBaseAmount($item->getBaseRowTotal());
           $address->setTotalQty($address->getTotalQty() + $item->getQty());
       }
   ```

   So new doubts:

   1. I wonder if I can "just like that" change this round to 4? I've seen some info that it can be problematic i.e. for Paypal
   2. How to get base price of item + add tax to have it rounded to 4 on a "magento automagic" way?

Now (of course it is a sily way to hardoce value - did it just for a test) in my cart I can see correct values - total 148.06

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking for will be in app/design/frontend/rwd/your_layout/template/catalog/product/price.phtml if you're using a custom layout or in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml if not.

It's a pretty confusing file, as it contains a whole bunch of conditions to help it decide which set of pricing rules to use, so figuring out which lines of of code it actually responsible for the price appearing on your pages can be tricky.
The trick I used to isolate the correct lines to modify in order to affect the prices shown in various places on our site was to add some arbitrary class names to the each of the various spans in price.phtml that look like they contain prices.(there's quite a lot of them, 40 or so I think).

So for example, I assigned each successive span of class "price" a new arbitrary class consisting simply of a number, starting at 1.

When i looked at the page from the front end with the element inspector, I discovered that all my configurable product prices shown on the product page had the class '28' and thus found that the lines I needed to modify were within the span to which I'd assigned the class 28

```
<span class="price 28">
          //change whatever code is here to get the result you want   
</span>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think that I need a backend solution to make sure that everything is going to work fine